# createFeatureSelector typescript error. "is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof AppState'."

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to create an ngrx feature selector with the following line:

```
export const selectCacheManagementState = createFeatureSelector<AppState, CacheManage mentState>('cachemanagement');
```

This is the error that I see:
Argument of type '"cachemanagement"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof AppState'.ts(2345)

I have seen this syntax work in many other examples (even others in the same app). Can someone explain what I may be missing?

This the interface for CacheManagementState:

```
export interface CacheManagementState {
  selectedCacheKey?: CacheKey;
  searchResult: CacheKey[];
  loading: boolean;
  error?: any;
  successfulSave: boolean;  
}
```

Let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

That overload is deprecated in v13.
Use the following instead, which will also fix the problem.

```
export const selectCacheManagementState = createFeatureSelector<CacheManage>('cachemanagement');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to NgRx and later realized that there was an object that managed the state that needed to be updated with the new state that I wanted to add. After adding the state to that object the other NgRx components (actions, effects, reducers, selectors, etc) worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I will take advantage on what @timdeschryver already said to explain your mistakes.
First of all you have a mistake in writing **CacheManage mentState** instead of **CacheManagementState** when exporting

> const selectCacheManagementState = createFeatureSelector<AppState,
> CacheManage mentState>('cachemanagement');

But I hope that mas only a typing mistake.
The core issue in your case is that you are facing the overlad issue due to your angular version which is different from that of the examples your following, because when you write

> createFeatureSelector<AppState,
> CacheManagementState>('cachemanagement')

Then **AppState** is your global state, **CacheManagementState** is a part of that global state and **('cachemanagement')** is the value you want to get from it.
in Angular in v13, this approach is an overload and deprecated.
To definitely solve that issue you will replace it with this:

> export const selectCacheManagementState = createFeatureSelector<
> CacheManagementState>('cachemanagement')

where again I remind any one having the save issue, **CacheManagementState** (implemented as an interface or not) is the part of the global state you want to get, and **'cachemanagement'** is the actual value rendered.